# EXCEL VBA: make first cell with partial text match activecell with macro run, then next cell down the list with subsequent macro runs activecell

Tags: excel, vba, search, select, partial

```
Sub AASearchForPartialText()
Dim SearchValue As String
SearchValue = Range("d2").Value
    Columns("D:D").Select
    Selection.Find(What:=SearchValue, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt _
        :=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:= _
        False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
End Sub
```

i am trying to simplify/make faster the excel search feature a bit by allowing the user to search through a long list of names (sometimes 2000) by typing in the partial string they want to find, and hitting the search button. the desired result is that it will cycle through the list of names, highlighting the next sequential cell that matches

the best that i am doing is highlighting the range d:d. can anyone help me out please?

i have included sample workbook for anyone kind enough

thank you all

https://www.dropbox.com/s/uahuzsu3a8qfv6z/searchpartial.xlsm

Comment: How are you making the search function faster/simpler? Excel's search function can already find partial strings.

Comment: i realize this, but cell d2 would be anchored to the top, and it would be nice to save the user the small amount of time going to the search function in the ribbon, or highlighting the cell, hitting ctrl+f and then searching. i realize this is only on the order of seconds, but if you do this a couple thousand times, the amount of time will add up

Answer (score 2):

i was actually able to figure this out one on my own with some help for other somewhat relevant code

sorry to waste anybody's time

```
Sub newsearchrecord()
Dim SearchValue As String
SearchValue = "*" & Range("D2").Value & "*"
    Cells.Find(What:=SearchValue, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:= _
        xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False _
        , SearchFormat:=False).Activate
    Cells.FindNext(After:=ActiveCell).Activate    
End Sub
```